# how to npm-run-all serial after nodemon starts

Tags: npm, nodemon, npm-scripts

I'm building a project with Node and React. In my `package.json` I have a bunch of scripts that use `npm-run-all` to aggregate these scripts in various different ways. I would like the front-end (React) projects to come up after the back-end is running, which seems easy enough with the `npm-run-all -s` option to serialise things. The problem I'm having is, in dev mode, I use `nodemon`, and since it sits and watches rather than exiting, nothing in serial after it ever gets run. I could just run the React stuff in parallel, but it tends to run faster than the back-end stuff, and so throws an error on first launch. Of course, this isn't the end of the world, but it would still be nice to find a workaround so the React stuff doesn't start until the backend is there. Any suggestions?

Here's a simplified `scripts`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "backend-dev": "run-p db-dev server-dev",
    ...
    "server-dev": "NODE_OPTIONS='--experimental-specifier-resolution=node  --trace-warnings' nodemon myapp start",
    ...
    "frontend-dev": "run-p frontend-apis-dev frontend-app-dev",
    "startdev": "run-s backend-dev frontend-dev",
  },
```

So, to be clear, if I `npm run startdev`, all of the `backend-dev` subsequent scripts run fine, but it never runs `frontend-dev` because after `backend-dev` -> `server-dev`, `nodemon` is just hanging out. How do I get it to execute the `frontend-dev` scripts after that point?

Or ... is there a better way to do this whole thing?

Thanks!